# How do I write a function in Python with a filename as an argument?

Tags: command-line, python, filename, functions, numpy

**EDIT:

Sorry if I was unclear. Let me clarify: I'm trying to write a function that takes a filename and a number i as arguments, loads the file specified by the filename with numpy.loadtxt(), and returns column number i (the file prints an array).

Essentially what I would like to do is:

```
def loadfile(filename.py, i):
    f = numpy.loadtxt('filename.py', usecols=(i))
    return(f)
```

But it doesn't even let me get past the first line, I get the error:

```
def loadfile(filename.py, i)
                     ^
Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax
```

So what I need help is somehow making a filename accepted as an argument, without getting that error message.

I've also tried

```
def loadfile(x, i):
    f = numpy.loadtxt('x', i)
    return(f)
```

And although that is accepted as a function, when I actually try to call it with a file name I get this error:

```
loadfile(sampledata.py, 2)
NameError: name 'sampledata' is not defined.
```

Bottom line: how can I use a filename as an argument?

*** the exact error message
[resulting TypeError Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqigg.png)

Comment: Literally all you need to do is set it to a string with an extension attached i.e. 'Test.py' and then open it in the appropriate manner.

Comment: Sorry about changing my mind about whether this is on-topic, but this is less of an OS issue and more of a programming issue, so it's better suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize this was off topic, this is my first time using this site. In any case my question was answered, but next time I will direct my question to Stack Overflow -- thanks for the heads up @wjandrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy

def loadfile(filename, i):
   return numpy.loadtxt(filename, usecols=(i,))
```

As an example, consider this file:

```
$ cat nums.txt
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then, observe `loadfile` successfully read in a column:

```
>>> loadfile('nums.txt', 2)
array([ 3.,  6.,  9.])
```

#### Notes

1. The `def` line of a function definition must end with `:`.
2. The arguments to a function need to be variables, like `filename`, not fixed strings like `'filename.py'`.
3. This will run but doesn't do what you want:

   ```
   def loadfile(x, i):
       f = numpy.loadtxt('x', i)
       return(f)
   ```

   The above takes `x` as an argument but then ignores it and attempts to load a file name whose name is the single character `x`.
4. This won't work either:

   ```
   def loadfile(filename.py, i):
       f = numpy.loadtxt('filename.py', usecols=(i))
       return(f)
   ```

   `filename.py` is not a valid name for a simple variable.  Even if it were, the code doesn't attempt to use that variable name.  Instead, it tries to load a file whose name is the string of characters `filename.py`.

Comment: @PattyB When testing my code, please don't retype it.  Copy-and-paste it exactly as it is.

Comment: I'm able to create the function just fine but then when I attempt to call it with a filename I get the TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Is this because I'm calling a .py file and not a .txt one? Also you said it needs to be a variable like filename but then when calling the function you use a fixed string 'nums.txt', could you explain why that's allowed? Thank you for your help!

Comment: (1) For the TypeError, please quote the exact error message.  (2) Inside the function, we need to use a variable name,  When calling the function, we can use either a variable or a string.  If we use a variable, it needs to have been previously assigned a value that matches a file name.

Comment: @PattyB I assume you're getting that TypeError because you made a typo: `usecols=i` instead of `usecols=(i)`.

Comment: @PattyB Another possibility for the TypeError is that you are using the old python2 instead of the current python3.  I updated the answer with code that will work on both.

Comment: @John1024 I've included a screenshot of my code and the exact error message at the very bottom of the original question above (I edited it to add the picture). Let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong. I am fairly certain I am using Python 3 (opened it with command ipython in terminal and it says Python 3.5.2 in the little blurb)

Comment: @PattyB Hmm.  Possibly, we are using different numpy versions.  Try my updated code which has the added comma: `return numpy.loadtxt(filename, usecols=(i,))`